# BinaryReader vs byte[]+shifts

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I must be misunderstanding what `BinaryReader` is doing. Why are these outputs different?

```
{
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(testFile);
    var pos = 0;
    var read8 = new Func<uint>(() => data[pos++]);
    var read32 = new Func<uint>(() => (read8() << 24) | (read8() << 16) | (read8() << 8) | read8());

    Console.WriteLine(read32());
}

using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(testFile, FileMode.Open)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadUInt32());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Endiannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Use:

```
var read32 = new Func<uint>(() => (read8() | (read8() << 8) | (read8() << 16) | read8() << 24));
```

On a side note, please don't write code with such side effects.
You are getting away with them here because [the order of evaluation is guaranteed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070814-00/?p=25593), but still please don't.

Comment: Right, of course. Thank you. 

On the side note I'm not sure I'm trackin' - is the order of evaluation not always (parens), functions(), and then operators? What is the side effect?

Comment: The side effect is the `++` inside the `read8`. That same code would look completely safe if it was a series of statements terminated by a semicolon, but a *single expression* where each member has a side effect that affects calculation of other members of the same expression is something you want to avoid - even though it does not lead to undefined behaviour like in C++ (see the link), it may still be very confusing.